# Wann heißt es "Nutznießer", "Nießnutzer" und wann "Genuss"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, meaning

Im täglichen Sprachgebrauch kenne ich das Wort *"[Nutznießer](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Nutznieszer)"*, mit dem eine Person umschrieben wird, die einen Nutzen oder einen Vorteil aus einem Vorgang zieht.

> Ich fasse einen Entschluss: Im kommenden Jahr will ich endlich ethisch korrekt leben, kein Klimakiller mehr sein und kein Nutznießer billiger Arbeitskräfte. <sup>[Die Zeit](http://www.zeit.de/2013/05/Lebensstil-Nachhaltig-Oekologisch-Fair-Bewusst)</sup>

Nun gibt es aber eine ganze Reihe von ähnlichen Wörtern, bei welchen mir Verwendung und damit womöglich unterschiedliche Bedeutung nicht so klar sind:

- "***Nießnutzer***" und "***Nießnutz***"
- "***Nutznießer***" und "***Nutznießung***" bzw. "das ***Nutznießen***"
- "***in den Genuss kommen***"

Je mehr ich über diese Wörter nachdenke, desto mehr bin ich verwirrt. Gibt es überhaupt einen Unterschied in der Bedeutung? Wann kann ich welchen Begriff (nicht) verwenden?

Nachdem die Verwendung von "Nießbraucher/Nießnutzer" (juristisch) und "Nutznießer" (allgemein) [beantwortet](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/6060/23) sind, stellt sich mir immer noch die Frage, inwieweit ***"in den Genuss kommen"*** oder ***"Nutznießer sein"*** synonym sind oder doch mit einer etwas unterschiedlichen Bedeutung verwendet werden. Stimmt mein subjektiver Eindruck, dass mit *Nutznießer* eine negative Bedeutung im Sinne von *"Schmarotzer"* mitschwingt? Ist das bei *"Genuss"* auch so?

Auch die Frage, wie die Substantive ***"der Nießnutz"***, ***"die Nutznießung"*** und ***"das Nutznießen"*** eingesetzt werden, bleibt noch unbeantwortet.

Beispiel:

> - Mit der neuen Kindertagesstätte kommen berufstätige Eltern in den Genuss einer umfassenden Betreuung ihrer Kinder.
> - Kinder berufstätiger Eltern sind Nutznießer der umfassenden Betreuung in der neuen Kindertagesstätte.
> - Nießnutzer der umfassenden Betreuung ihrer Kinder in der neuen Kindertagesstätte sind berufstätige Eltern.

**Anmerkung:** Wie aus den Kommentaren zu entnehmen, ist der Begriff *"Nießbrauch"* wohl ausschließlich dem juristischen Fachgebrauch vorbehalten. Allerdings wäre es schon auch interessant, ob es irgendwann früher eine Verwendung außerhalb der Fachsprache gab.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ich persönlich habe den Begriff "Nießbrauch" auch nur in dem Zusammenhang mit einer bestimmten rechtlichen Konstruktion gehört.

Den Begriff "Nießnutzer" dagegen kenne ich gar nicht aus dem Alltag, [Duden.de](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Niesznutzer) gibt als Bedeutung "jemand, der das Nießbrauchsrecht von etwas genießt".

Dagegen lese (und höre) ich "Nutznießer" relativ häufig, wobei die Synonyme, die Duden.de [in diesem Fall](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Nutznieszer) angibt, für mein Sprachempfinden zu negativ geprägt sind ("Schmarotzer"). Ich halte den Begriff für relativ neutral (hier bin ich aber gespannt, ob das nur subjektiv ist).

> Wann kann ich welchen Begriff (nicht) verwenden?

Ich persönlich würde den Begriff "Nießnutzer" zugunsten von "Nießbraucher" meiden, wenn es um die entsprechende juristische Konstruktion geht. Davon abgesehen würde ich derzeit "Nutznießer" ohne Bedenken verwenden, wenn es ein neutrales Synonym zu "Profiteur" sein soll.

Answer (score 3):

Fangen wir mit dem "Nutznießer" an. Das Wort ist allgemein gebräuchlich und bezeichnet jemanden, der *Nutzen* aus einer Sache zieht. Synonyme dafür sind "Begünstigter" oder "Profiteur". Das Verb "nießen" (auch Zusammensetzungen mit "-nieß-") bedeutet soviel wie "benutzen", ist heute aber ausgestorben. Es kommt allerdings in Zusammensetzungen wie "genießen" noch vor.

Das Wort "Nießnutzen" (bzw. ähnliche Bildungen: "Nießnutzer", "Nießbrauch", ...) ist ein Begriff aus dem Rechtswesen, der sich unmittelbar von dem oben beschriebenen "nießen" ableitet. Er bezeichnet das Recht (oder auch dessen Ausübung) der Verfügung über eine Sache bzw. der Sachen, die daraus entstehen. (Wenn ich eine Kuh habe, dann kann ich nicht nur über diese verfügen, sondern auch über die Milch, die sie gibt, die Butter, die ich aus der Milch mache, etc., dasselbe gilt für Früchte von Bäumen.)

Aus dem rechtlichen Bereich kommt auch der "Genuß" - wenigstens in der hier einschlägigen Bedeutung. Er bedeutet die Verfügungsgewalt über etwas, das sich aus aus einer Sache ableitet. zB. könnte man einen Baum zwar nicht besitzen, dafür aber das Recht, die Früchte zu *genießen* - soll heißen, sie zu essen, zu verkaufen, etc.. Wer etwa eine Wohnung *genießt*, dem gehört sie vielleicht (oder auch nicht), aber auf jeden Fall darf er dort wohnen.

Kurz ein Wort noch zum Gebrauch des Wortes *Genuß* außerhalb der rechtlichen Sphäre: das bedeutet ein Wohlbehagen, das durch die Konsumation von etwas verursacht wird. Natürlich ist es möglich, diese Bedeutung sarkastisch zu konterkarieren - wie in einem Kommentar angemerkt, kann man in den *Genuß* einer Sonderbehandlung kommen - aber das ändert nichts an der Bedeutung des Wortes "Genuß". Im Gegenteil wird die sarkastische Zuspitzung ja eben erst durch die übliche, gegenteilige Bedeutung ermöglicht. Sigmund Freud merkt in seiner Abhandlung "Der Witz und seine Beziehung zum Unterbewußten" an, daß Witz durch die Verschiebung des Kontexts entstehe. Im Falle von Sarkasmus geschieht diese Kontextverschiebung dadurch, daß man die Bedeutung von Wörtern "umdreht" und in ihr Gegenteil verkehrt. Dazu muß aber erst eine bestimmte Bedeutung, die man dann umkehren kann, vorhanden sein.

Wer etwa aus einer Warteschlange herausgerufen und sofort drangenommen wird, der kommt tatsächlich in den "Genuß" einer "Sonderbehandlung". Erst auf diesem Hintergrund ist die sarkastische Umkehrung im Falle einer Sonderbehandlung, die weniger "Genuß" bedeutet, möglich - eben weil es hier einen Kontext gibt, der verschoben werden kann.

Answer (score 2):

Der Begriff ***Nutznießer*** bezeichnet, in Abgrenzung zur Formulierung ***in den Genuss kommen***, jemanden, der von einer Sache profitiert, ohne eine Gegenleistung dafür zu erbringen. Daher kann die Bedeutung auch in Richtung ***Schmarotzer*** gehen, muss sie aber nicht.

Die Formulierung ***in den Genuss kommen*** sagt lediglich neutral aus, dass jemand eine Sache genießt bzw. Freude daraus zieht. Hier gibt es keinen Hinweis darauf, ob der Genuss selbst erarbeitet wurde oder nicht. Bspw. kann man ***die Früchte seiner Arbeit genießen*** bzw. ***in den Genuss der Früchte seiner Arbeit kommen***, womit eine gegensätzliche Bedeutung zum Nutznießer vorhanden wäre.
Außerdem wird ***in den Genuss kommen*** auch verwendet, um z.B. den Verzehr einer Speise oder generell den Konsum einer Sache zu bezeichnen.

Comment: Und warum komme ich dann in den Genuss einer Sonderbehandlung? D=

Comment: Weil "in den Genuss" kommen neutral ist. Es kann in beide Richtungen gehen. Schrieb ich doch schon in meiner Antwort. :)

Comment: Aber »sagt […] neutral aus, dass jemand […] Freude daraus zieht«; das passt nicht ganz zu einer typischen Sonderbehandlung ;)

Comment: Das Ziel meiner Antwort war es nicht, eine vollumfängliche Bedeutung für "Genuss" bzw. die Wendung "in den Genuss kommen" zu geben, sondern es von "Nutznießung" abzugrenzen.

Comment: Ein *Nutznießer* kann durchaus eine Gegenleistung für den Nießnutz erbringen - Der Begriff impliziert in keinster Weise "keine Gegenleistung", sondern nur "hat was davon".